# your project requires a newer version of the kotlin gradle plugin error

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, gradle, flutter-build

When I try to build app it throws error - **your project requires a newer version of the kotlin gradle plugin**.

```
 [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                                                                            │
│ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, 
| then update E:\flutter_apps\geodata\android\build.gradle: │
│ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'
```

I have already upgrade my android/build.gradle as below.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And my android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties as below

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip
```

Please any one can help me?

Comment: Modify ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.10'

Comment: I did this but it shows warning - Kotlin version that is used for building with Gradle (1.8.10) differs from the one bundled into the IDE plugin (1.7.20)

Comment: steel that error with -- ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.10'

Comment: Update your kotlin plugin in Android Studio

Comment: in Android Studio latest kotlin version shows 1.8.0 - I updrage to 1.8.0 and set ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0' then steel same problem

Comment: @DhavalChaudhari same here, mind if i ask what was your solution?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. and I tried multiple solutions. none worked.
finally got the solution.
copy and past the below code in android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

}
```

and also change `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip` in android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue when I updated to Flutter 3.13.3 which requires higher Kotlin version, and you can find latest Kotlin version here [Kotlin Releases](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details).
then go to `android/build.gradle` and edit Kotlin Version as following:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.9.10" //Update with the latest version
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was caused by a previous error:

SigningConfig "release" is missing required property 'storeFile'

After I update android/app/build.gradle, with storeFile, and ./android/key.properties file

This "newer version of the kotlin" error just go away.

It's a wrong error message in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have just upgrade the kotlin version 1.6.10 to 1.7.10 and solved my issue

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.7.10" //just updated
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Flutter Project's build.gradle -

```
see this block - 

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.22' // replace with lastest version(below link) 
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
}


This is link - https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.9.22
```

[This is the link for latest version of Kotlin](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.9.22)

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the solutions given in this thread but non worked. The issue was like there is no buildscript section in my build.gradle file. I tried adding the ones that are in this thread and still isnt working even after updating to 1.9.22 (the latest version).

This error message is showing up now.
[image: Error Message]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35699648)